# Do coffins block movement?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Do coffins block the movement of dwarves, like statues seem to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, coffins do not block movement.

PROTIP: mined-out and engraved clusters/veins of precious minerals are a great place for a snotty noble's tomb.

Comment: I hope my answer is not the reason for that!

Comment: Don't worry, the dwarves just liked each other really much when the Queen Vampire ate one, one thing led to another and now there's 120 dwarves (and counting) to bury, if anyone survives. Who'd have known tantrums were contagious?

Comment: @Anna Welcome to Dwarf Fortress! Contagious tantrums are the #1 cause of fortress failure. Most of us consider this Fun.